# Chrome Profiles for Syncing Locally Stored Extension Data Between Browsers

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Curious if anyone's seen/heard anything on the ability to use Chrome Profiles to allow synchronization of data contained within extensions between computers.

Put another way, I would like the ability to synchronize / access localStorage from multiple computers signed in with the same browser profile.

Nothing from Google on this now, AFAIK.  Anyone know any differnetly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome has an [experimental API](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/experimental.storage.html) that allows syncing of data. Hopefully it will be in stable within the next couple of months.

Comment: Not sure _how_ I missed that.  Exactly what I was looking for.